# How to watch for conditional child class of StateNotifier in RiverPod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Building off [class that indirectly extends from StateNotifier in StateNotifierProvider doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459434/class-that-indirectly-extends-from-statenotifier-in-statenotifierprovider-doesn)

I will have `abstract DogNotifier extends StateNotifier<DogInfo>`  and some children notifiers ShibaNotifier,  that extend it.

However, in the UI, not sure the best way to handle:

I was thinking of having another provider aka KennelNotifier which would keep track of which Dog we are looking at in a DogNotifier whichDog() method.

So that I can reuse the UI like:

ref.watch(ref.read(kennelNotifier).whichDog))

But this has to be wrong or is it ok? Wondering how I can reuse my UI code for a Dog in a conditional way like this as I still would like a ShibaNotifier and a LabradorNotifier etc.

Thank you.

Comment: I made a proof of concept but it uses ref.watch twice: https://github.com/hunterpp/riverpod_child_provider/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

So,

it probably is possible to get providers dynamically: https://github.com/hunterpp/riverpod_child_provider/blob/ff30883e5c502b5e821f3c4bb8cc4a93dec21d65/lib/main.dart#L53

but it involved multiple calls to ref.watch:
`Text(ref.watch(ref.watch(kennelProvider).dog.notifier).produce()),`

And not sure that is idiomatic and feels risky.

What I settled on was using family:

https://github.com/hunterpp/riverpod_child_provider/blob/main/lib/main.dart

And explicitly passing a type to get the correct child notifier

```
Text(ref.watch(dogProvider(DogType.pittie).notifier).produce()),
Text(ref.watch(dogProvider(DogType.shiba).notifier).produce()),
```